# Is it possible to display the contents of objects in the chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a line, I yuhe output it to the console but get the types of object[object].

```
  console.log(`%c ${args[args.length-1]} ${performance['now'](true, args[args.length-1])} [(${args.slice(0, args.length-1)} *) ${message}]`, 'color:' + color)
```

[image: result]

Is it possible to flaunt the contents of objects?

```
console.log(`%c ${args[args.length-1]} ${performance['now'](true, args[args.length-1])} [(${args.slice(0, args.length-1)} *) ${message}]`, 'color:' + color)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're encoding those objects as a string. Instead you can pass the value directly to `console.log` in order to get rich exploration of that data.

```
var a = { a: 123 }
var b = { b: 456 }
console.log('string', a, b)
```

Result:

[image: console]

Just note that your color tagging *only* works when displaying strings, because for objects the console uses it's own way of displaying it so that it can do syntax highlighting, show/hide properties and other useful interactions.

[image: console styled]